# _TypeError thrown building LandingPage(dirty,dependencies:[_InheritedProviderScope<AppState?>]) type _Type is not a subtype of type String in typecast

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-change-notifier, flutter-change-notifier-provider

I am new to flutter and trying to develop a login screen, I am facing issue while implementing ChangeNotifierProvider. I tried using both MultiProvider and ChangeNotifierProvider widgets and both produces same exception.

**Exception**

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building LandingPage(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<AuthState?>]):
type '_Type' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

The relevant error-causing widget was:
    LandingPage LandingPage:file:///Users/hatimtai/Flutter%20Projects/myapp/lib/main.dart:32:21

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      new AuthState (package:myapp/states/auth_state.dart:4:27)
#1      MyApp.build.<anonymous closure> (package:myapp/main.dart:23:53)
#2      _CreateInheritedProviderState.value (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:736:36)
#3      _InheritedProviderScopeElement.value (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:590:33)
#4      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:303:37)
#5      LandingPage.build (package:myapp/main.dart:43:32)
#6      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5541:49)
#7      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5471:15)
#8      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
#9      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
#10     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
...     Normal element mounting (220 frames)
#230    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
#231    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6871:36)
#232    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6883:32)
...     Normal element mounting (453 frames)
#685    _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:411:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#692    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#699    _NestedHookElement.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:187:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#706    _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:411:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#713    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#720    _NestedHookElement.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:187:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#727    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (33 frames)
#760    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
#761    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
#762    _RawViewElement._updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/view.dart:289:16)
#763    _RawViewElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/view.dart:312:5)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#770    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
#771    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
#772    RootElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1334:16)
#773    RootElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1303:5)
#774    RootWidget.attach.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1256:18)
#775    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2835:19)
#776    RootWidget.attach (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1255:13)
#777    WidgetsBinding.attachToBuildOwner (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1083:27)
#778    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1065:5)
#779    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1051:7)
#783    _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
(elided 3 frames from class _Timer and dart:async-patch)
```

I am following google codelabs ["Your first Flutter app"](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-codelab-first#0), have gone through it multiple times and am not able to find what is going wrong and hence need your help.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/states/auth_state.dart';
import 'package:myapp/states/myapp_state.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:myapp/pages/login_page.dart';
import 'package:myapp/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:myapp/utils/login_utils.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => MyAppState()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AuthState()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
              seedColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 31, 136, 105)),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home: const LandingPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandingPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authState = Provider.of<AuthState>(context);

    Widget page;
    bool isUserLoggedIn = false;
    isLoggedIn(authState.refreshToken, authState.accessToken)
        .then((value) => isUserLoggedIn = value);

    switch (isUserLoggedIn) {
      case true:
        page = const HomePage();
        break;
      default:
        page = const LoginPage();
    }

    return page;
  }
}
```

**states/auth_state.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthState extends ChangeNotifier {
  var refreshToken = Null as String;
  var accessToken = Null as String;

  void setCredentials(String refresh, String access) {
    refreshToken = refresh;
    accessToken = access;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**states/myapp_state.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var refreshToken = Null as String;` is the problem. [`Null`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Null-class.html) is a type. If you want to set the value to null, use `null` (small 'n' letter). And you can't cast a null to `String`. Type-annotate the variable with `String?` instead.

```dart
String? refreshToken; // No need "= null", nullable variable is null by default
```

You might want to try the [Null safety codelab](https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety).

---

See also:

- [Sound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)
- [Understanding null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the codelab link !!! I was able to fix the issue :).